# combobox dinamico con php, ajax y mysql: Solo me muestra un resultado en el segundo select cuando deberían ser varios

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin, combobox

Tengo una base de datos en mysql que gestiono com phpmyadmin y en mi desarrollo web (historial.php) quiero poner un combobox dinamico de manera que al elegir el campo obra, me muestre los bloques de esa obra para elegir uno de ellos. De momento me deja elegir la obra correctamente, pero el problema es que el segundo select (getbloque.php) solo me muestra un bloque, que si corresponde con la obra elegida, pero se que esa obra tiene mas bloques y solo me muestra uno de ellos.

El codigo del archivo historial.php contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

require ('sistema.php');

?>  

<head>
    <title>Historial por vivienda</title> 
    
    <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    
    
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        
        $("#cbx_centro_coste").change
        (function () 
        {
            
            //$('#cbx_ubicacion').find('option').remove().end().append
            //('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');
            
            $("#cbx_centro_coste option:selected").each
            (function () 
            {
                Id_CentroCoste = $(this).val();
                $.post("includes/getbloque.php", {Id_CentroCoste:Id_CentroCoste},
                function(data) 
                {
                    $("#cbx_bloque").html(data);
                
                }
                );
            }
            );
        }
        )
    }
    );
    </script>       
    
<body>
    
    <div>
            <main>
                <div>
                    <h1>Historial por vivienda</h1>
                </div>
                
                <?php
                $query = ("SELECT * FROM `centros de coste` ORDER BY `centros de coste`.`N DE OBRA` DESC");
                $resultado = $mysqli->query($query)
                ?>
                
                <form id="combo" name="combo" action="guarda.php" method="POST">
                
                    <div>Seleccionar obra:
                        <select id="cbx_centro_coste" name="cbx_centro_coste">
                            <option value="0">Seleccionar obra</option>
                            
                            <?php WHILE ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['Id_CentroCoste'];?>"> <?php echo $row['CENTRO DE COSTE'];?> </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
                
                </form>
                
                <div>Seleccionar bloque:
                
                    <select id="cbx_bloque" name="cbx_bloque"></select>
                    
                </div>
                
            </main>
            
    </div>
   
</body>

</head>
```

Por, otro lado el archivo getbloque.php contiene el codigo siguiente:

```
<?php
      require "../sistema.php";
?>

<?php   

$Id_CentroCoste = $_POST['Id_CentroCoste'];

$queryB = "SELECT `Id_Bloques`, `BLOQUE N`, `CENTRO DE COSTE` FROM `bloques_centro de coste` WHERE `CENTRO DE COSTE` = '$Id_CentroCoste' ORDER BY `bloques_centro de coste`.`BLOQUE N` ASC";

$resultadoB = $mysqli -> query($queryB);

$html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar bloque</option>";

WHILE ($rowB = $resultadoB -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $html = "<option value='".$rowB['Id_Bloques']."'>".$rowB['BLOQUE N']."</option>";
}

echo $html;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que este es el problema

```
WHILE ($rowB = $resultadoB -> fetch_assoc())
{
    $html .= "<option value='".$rowB['Id_Bloques']."'>".$rowB['BLOQUE N']."</option>";
}
```

en el código original está sobreescribiendo el valor de `$html` tiene que concatenar los valores tal como le puse arriba

Saludos

Comment: Mil gracias rene. Ese era el problema y no me habia dado cuenta. Muchisimas gracias, has sido de gran ayuda.

Comment: Por nada me alegro que haya resuelto el problema, recuerda aceptar la respuesta Gracias ;)